# Freeze after login Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, login, freeze, 18.04

Before the upgrade I was using gnome on Ubuntu 16.04 with lightdm and it worked fine. After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 I switched to gnome gdm3. On the first day I could login to my user account, configure gnome and so on. However on the next day when I tried to login for the first time, the login screen just comes back again and when I try it for a second time it just freezes. Can someone help me with this problem?

In advance thanks for help.

UPDATE: I switched back to lightdm and it works just fine. However I would still like to use gdm3 because I like it more. How could I do this?

Comment: I am also having a problem with gdm3 and I have to use lightdm with 18.04. Log out and log in with another user will result into same blank screen. I can log in after boot however and funny enough with the same user I previously logged out. It will not make any difference with wayland or xorg. I tried to edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncomment: WaylandEnable=false (someone had this idea), but that resulted into freeze after log out even before selecting a login user.

Comment: I confirm the same issue on my lenovo yoga pro 3 - which means no nvidia - and some other entries related to this issue suggested it may be caused by nvidia

Comment: I,m using integrated video card because there is no drivers for my amd radeon r7 m260. So it doesn't really help me

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223515/225694) to the aforementioned question could be useful to you.

Comment: My Dell Inspiron 7559 has the same problem.  Have rebooted 100 times, the system always freezes immediately after I input my account password except only once it magically works.  I can log in after I switched to lightdm.

Comment: I tried to edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and comment WaylandEnable=false again, because I had this problem with 17.10 I had commented WaylandEnable=false, but now after upgrading to 18.04 and updating my gpu driver to 390, this problem comes up again. I don't know why ctrl+alt+f2 didn't work!! Fortunately I had a live cd of 13.04 and it let me access custom.conf and I put a # behind WaylandEnable=false and save the file and restart my pc and it is working now. My session is set on ubuntu .

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to install your graphics drivers.

On your login page, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Enter your credentials and use the below commands (if you're using Nvidia graphics card)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
```

If you're using some other graphics card then use

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

to find out your recommended driver - as suggested by Joe.

Comment: I was trying to search for video drivers for my amd radeon r7 m260 but i can not find any for ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You can try installing the one which you used for your previous version of Ubuntu.

Comment: The funny part is that on Ubuntu 16.04 (that i had before) the drivers for my video card were not working properly, however i read that 17.10 drivers worked for that specific video card. At the moment amd webpage doesnt really give any good drivers for my video card.

Comment: Okay try this, it worked with my Nvidia graphics card. Use the settings button on login page and select "Ubuntu on Wayland" and then try logging in. It should show your desktop in a few minutes. Remember to give it time for the first login.

Comment: Use `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` to find out your recommended driver.

Comment: It wouldn't even let me get into the console on my Dell Inspiron 7559. @SankalpKotewar's suggestion worked for me.

Comment: This worked great! Spent days figuring out what the problem was on my DELL XPS 15 9560. Thanks!

Comment: nvidia-390 is super specific .... why this one? I'm also gonna assume that this will NOT be the same one in the future (read: By the time someone finds this on Google a year+ later)

Comment: ^ Ok, Ubuntu 18 update: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` >> `sudo apt update` >> `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` (note the highest # recommended driver. Mine was `396`. Thx @JoeEifert) >> `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-396` // Replace `396` with your own #. Note the syntax for installing the nvidia driver is changed from the answer above (maybe they changed it, or maybe answer was wrong? Not sure). AS A SIDE NOTE >> If you're freezing @ login, press `CTRL+ALT+F2` @ login screen to drop to console immediately; or run it after grub recovery if you freeze before logging in.