# Ubuntu 18.04.1 freezes after loging in

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, freeze

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 (Dual boot with win.10), and ever since the first login, it'd freeze after i logged in (typed pass & enter). The cursor would get stuck, and nothing would happen. 
My current work-around/fix is booting through recovery mode/dpkg, and then resume normal boot.
Now after doing some googling, i found that it might be related to graphics driver (Nvidia), so i followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030060/freeze-after-login-ubuntu-18-04) solotion. I have HP with Nvidia 1050, & am not sure if it's the right driver.

I'm also relatively new to the linux environement, so i don't know how to trouble shooot. So thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Ok so I continued to do some googling, and since I have a clean install I didn't mind the risk of experimenting. Therefore, first went on Software Update/Settings/Additional Drivers, and chose Nvidia 396 (instead of 390), which led me to a login loop. 
Thereafter I followed the FIRST instruction [here](https://www.linuxslaves.com/2016/05/3-ways-fix-ubuntu-gets-stuck-login-loop.html), but no fix.

Finally, I booted through FailsafeX, and chose X.org X server driver instead. I restarted a couple of times, even started windows just to be sure, and it now seems to work.

PS: I don't know exactly what happened, and I'm almost certain that it will reverse soon enough, so if someone knows a solid fix, pls let me know! and if this is a fix, hope it helps :)