# Unmet dependencies error while removing NVIDIA drivers/files

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, cuda, gpu

System information:

```
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
ACER E5-573G
NVIDIA GeForce 940M
```

I am trying to download nvidia drivers, CUDA toolkit and cudnn files to use tensorflow with the GPU.

I managed to download CUDA toolkit and nvidia drivers through some tutorials.

I downloaded the drivers directly from the nvidia website and the file name is 'NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.87.run'. To download CUDA toolkit, since on the nvidia website it is only available for Ubuntu 17.10 and 16.04, I used some command to download and install the toolkit(which unfortunately I don't remember but it downloaded 9.1 version).

Then using chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.87.run,  I made it an executable and then using ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.87.run I tried to install it!  But it somehow finished the installation process with some error message in between saying 'pre-installation failed!do you wish to continue?' I continued anyways.

Now when I logged back in after I write in my credentials, the screen froze so I used https://askubuntu.com/a/1030490 to solve the error.

But the problem is when I tried running 'nvidia-settings', it says 'ERROR: Unable to find display on any available system'.

Knowing that I made a mess, I tried purging all the nvidia files but it says

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia-390 (the command I wrote into terminal)

Reading package lists ...Done
Buildig dependency tree
Reading state information..Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not going to 
be installed
libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390(=390.87- 
0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed.
Recommends: Depends: libnvidia-gl-390(=390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 
it is not going to be installed.
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages 
(or specify a solution.)
```

When I run apt --fix-broken install, it again says some version mismatch and unmet dependency error!

It is really frustrating! Please help me solve this issue. Can I not uninstall every nvidia file and start from start?

Thanks :)

PS: Also I am using Ubuntu Wayland in Login as the normal Ubuntu either zooms up the display to a much lower resolution or freezes the screen!

Comment: There is no nvidia-390 package in the standard repositories (no need for the graphics drivers ppa), it's now called nvidia-driver-390. I thought using Nvidia drivers would suppress the Wayland option?

Comment: @ubfan1 I am actually a bit new to this process! How do I uninstall everything related to nvidia and start a new installation process?

Comment: Hello! Since we have such a big "Ubuntu expert community" here, still nobody can answer, I have to uninstall the whole ubuntu now. Reinstall it and reinstall all the nvidia packages!

Comment: Wait a bit, people are all in different time zones.  Or use the site's search function and look for "uninstall nvidia"  -- you get over 1000 hits.  List the nvidia packages (dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia  ) , remove them (sudo apt-get purge nvidia-whatever), ensure there's no "blacklist nouveau"  left in any file in /etc/modprobe.d, remove your graphics-driver ppa, then reinstall the nvidia-driver-390.

Comment: I can't exactly flag, nor comment on your post to send you over to another link, so I'll post this here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072999/nvidia-driver-problem-after-apt-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04/1073157#1073157